# Standard way of building an arbitrary length table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm receiving data from a websocket (live stream), and trying to put it into a table. I'm currently using the following code:

```
var table = document.getElementById("websocket-data");
function writeToScreen(message) {
    var new_row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = new_row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = new_row.insertCell(1);
    var obj = JSON.parse(message.data);
    console.log(obj.value);
    cell1.innerHTML = obj.id;
    cell2.innerHTML = obj.value;
}
```

This works, and creates a new row for every JSON packet. The functionality that I am looking for is: On receipt of a JSON, if the id is not in the table, then create a row with id and value, however, if the id is already in the table, simply update the value. I've come across a few ways of doing this, but I'd like to know what the 'proper' way to do it is. I was thinking that perhaps the data should go into an array, and then the array should populate the table, but that would involve repopulating the entire table every time the array changed... I'm happy to use JQuery or similar if necessary.

Comment: So search the table for the id before adding... Personally I would just use an array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array and repopulate the table every time like you said, and if the table will only ever be small then you may not run into issues with that.

One possible alternative of many is maintaining an object in the background with your ids as keys and then store the value and the table row index as values.

Something like:

```
var tableStore = {};

function recieveMessage(message) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(message);

    // if the id is not in the tableStore, add it!
    if (tableStore[obj.id] === undefined) {
        // insert new row into table and save the index into `newTableRowIndex`

        // store a blank value (updated below) and the index in the table where it will be displayed
        tableStore[obj.id] = {value: undefined, tableIndex: newTableRowIndex};
    }

    // if the value recieved is different than the stored value, update the row
    if (obj.value !== tableStore[obj.id].value) {
        tableStore[obj.id].value = obj.value; // store the new value
        var row = getTableRow(tableStore[obj.id].tableIndex); // your own function to get the row based on index
        // update the row to display the new information
    }
}
```

This could be improved and made to be more organized but you should get the idea.

This way it would only update anything in the display if the new information recieved is different than the old information already stored.

This way should also perform better than using an array would if the table has the potential to get very large as you would not need to search through the entire array every time to see if the id is already stored or not. You would simply access the tableStore entry directly using the id.

Comment: Thanks, but it throws the following error:Uncaught ReferenceError: newTableRowIndex is not defined

Comment: @Alex Did you read all the comments? You have to define that yourself. See the comment in the code that says "// insert a new row into the table and **save the index into** `newTableRowIndex`" You will have to fill in some things yourself, this was just meant to show you one possible strategy you can use.